# Automatically add braces after _ and ^ in math mode with Aquamacs

Tags: math-mode, editors, texshop, aquamacs

In Texshop there is a very useful tool. When I type `_` or `^` in math mode, the braces appear automatically. Is there an analogous tool in Aquamacs?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: This is certainly not an answer and barely a comment, but as an aside: you'll find that Aquamacs (which is based on / a fork of the unbelievably popular editor Emacs) can do *literally anything* you can think of, via the Emacs LISP language it is based upon.  Some tools are built in, as you can see from giorano's answer, and some tools you can simply build yourself (or, of course, ask here or on SO).  So yes, there is *always* an 'analogous tool.' :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Preferences.el` file (the init file for Aquamacs) put this code

```lisp
(setq TeX-electric-sub-and-superscript t)
```

Comment: AucTeX is magic.

Comment: @SeanAllred yep, and next version will be even more magic: for example, it'll be easy to enter math mode `$...$` or `\(...\)` by pressing `$`. You'll need to customize a single variable to do that. Until now, instead, people use `electric-pair-mode` or bind `$` to a custom function.

Comment: This just in: AucTeX 11.87 and the infinite possibilities of authorized legilimency.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. Can you explain me how to use electric-pair-mode for math mode, please?

Comment: @Fra I don't use it, so I cannot explain how exactly works.  If I remember correctly you have to bind `$` to `self-insert-command`, but I suggest you not to do so if you don't want to lose all AUCTeX features about `$` insertion.